# when i search a letter with number it show error?

Tags: php

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("corporate_personnel_order_for_2016") or die(mysql_error());
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obs WHERE OBS_NUMBER LIKE $search;") or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table><tr><th width=250>OBS Number</th><th width=250>Name</th><th width=250>Purpose</th><th width=250>Date of OB</th><th width=250>Destination</th></tr>";



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<td width=250>' . $row['OBS_NUMBER'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>' . $row['NAME'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>' . $row['PURPOSE'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>' . $row['DATE_OF_OB'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td width=250>' . $row['DESTINATION'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
echo "</table>";
```

when i search an entry with letter and number it cant shows an error but when I search a number only it shows to my table?

Comment: `LIKE '$search'` try doing it with a single quote

Comment: it show this error

Comment: Unknown column '$search' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obs WHERE OBS_NUMBER LIKE '".$search."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

or this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM obs WHERE OBS_NUMBER LIKE '%".$search."%'") or die(mysql_error());
```